# Calculator for the area of various 3D figures, using abstract classes and inheritance

Tags: java, beginner, calculator, inheritance

I am a Java newbie, and they have just recently taught us abstract classes and inheritance. While I was practising, I wondered whether I can make multiple instances of the same abstract method in different classes. (We didn't go that far, and my knowledge about this is what I have gleaned during our professor writing code in front of us.) My curiosity led me to write this code, that I have posted here. It compiles and runs fine, AFAIK; but, I would like this to be simpler and more succinct, if possible.

```
import java.math.*;
import java.util.*;

abstract class Figure{
                        // I cant have 2 constructors with same      parameters it seems.
                        // so side1 has to float otherwise it creates an ambiguity error with 
                        //radius
    final double PI = 3.14;
    double side, height,base;
    int radius;
    float side1;
    Figure(float s1)
    {
        side1 = s1;//cube
    }
    Figure(double h1, int r1)// cone uses side instead of height to resolve ambiguity
    {
        height = h1;//cone 
        radius = r1;
    }
    Figure(int r1)
    {
        radius = r1;//sphere
    }
    Figure(int r1,double h1)
    {
        radius =r1;
        height = h1;//cylinder
    }
    Figure(double h1,double b1)
    {
        base = b1;
        height = h1;//pyramid
    }
    abstract double areaCalculator();

}

class Cube extends Figure{

    double result;
    Cube(float s1)
    {
        super(s1);
    }

    double areaCalculator()
    {
        result = 6 * Math.pow(side1,2); 
        return result;
    }

}

class Cone extends Figure{

    double result;
    Cone(double h1, int r1)
    {
        super(h1,r1);
    }

    double areaCalculator()
    {
        result = (PI * height * radius) + (PI * Math.pow(radius,2));
        return result;
    }

}

class Sphere extends Figure{

    double result;
    Sphere(int r1)
    {
        super(r1);
    }

    double areaCalculator()
    {
        result = PI * 4.0 * Math.pow(radius,2);
        return result;
    }


}

class Cylinder extends Figure{

    double result;
    Cylinder(int r1, double h1)
    {
        super(r1, h1);
    }

    double areaCalculator()
    {
        result = (2.0 * PI * Math.pow(radius,2)) + (2.0 * PI * radius * height);
        return result;
    }

}

class Pyramidsqbase extends Figure{

    double result;
    Pyramidsqbase(double b1, double h1)
    {
        super(h1,b1);
    }

    double areaCalculator()
    {
        result = Math.pow(base,2) + (2.0 * base * height);
        return result;
    }

}

class Newsurfaceareacalc2{

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        double result,side, height, base;
        int choice, radius;
        float side1;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Surface area Calculator:");
        System.out.println("1 for cube, 2 for cone, 3 for sphere, 4 for cylinder, 5 for square-base pyramid.");
            choice = sc.nextInt();

        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1: System.out.println("Enter value of side of cube:");//cube
                side1 = sc.nextFloat();
                Cube c1 = new Cube(side1);
                result = c1.areaCalculator();
                System.out.println("Result is "+ result);
                    break;

            case 2: System.out.println("Enter value of radius of cone:");//cone
                radius = sc.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Enter value of height of cone:");
                height = sc.nextDouble();
                Cone c2 = new Cone(height, radius);
                result = c2.areaCalculator();
                System.out.println("Result is "+ result);
                break;

            case 3: System.out.println("Enter value of radius of sphere:");//sphere
                radius = sc.nextInt();
                Sphere s2 = new Sphere(radius);
                result = s2.areaCalculator();
                System.out.println("Result is "+ result);
                break;

            case 4: System.out.println("Enter value of radius of cylinder:");//cylinder
                radius = sc.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Enter value of of height of cylinder:");
                height = sc.nextDouble();
                Cylinder c3 = new Cylinder(radius, height);
                result = c3.areaCalculator();
                System.out.println("Result is "+ result);
                break;
            case 5: System.out.println("Enter value of base in pyramid");//pyramid
                base = sc.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("Enter value of height in pyramid:");
                height = sc.nextDouble();
                Pyramidsqbase p1 = new Pyramidsqbase(base, height);
                result = p1.areaCalculator();
                System.out.println("Result is "+ result);
                break;

            default: System.out.println("Error.");
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. I don't think there's a point in having multiple constructors in the `Figure` class. I don't see why it should have any fields at all. I'd suggest to store the data in its subclasses (so that each subclass has only the fields it actually uses. It makes no sense for the `Cube` to have the `radius` field, for instance). Actually, the `Figure` could be an interface with just one method for computing the area.
2. I would also create methods to read the input for each specific figure and print the result (so that each `case` clause just calls the corresponding method). It will also help to get rid of a bunch of variables declared at the top of the `main` method (they reduce the code readability because their declaration point is far from their first usage. Moreover, some of them are never used depending on the user input).

Answer (score 0):

> I wondered whether I can make multiple instances of the same abstract method in different classes.

You cannot make instances of *methods*. You can only make instances of *classes*. These instances are *objects*. Objects *have* methods which are defined in their class.

Classes can extend each other (one direction). This is called *inheritance*.

In java we have two different kinds of inheritance:

1. Method definition inheritance

   You can declare *abstract* methods where you only provide the *signature* of the method but no content. 
   This type of inheritance can be provided  by *abstract classes* or *interfaces* (the latter is preferred).

   ```
   interface Animal{
     // defines that every animal is able to make sound,
     // even fish... ;o)
     String makeSound(); 
   }

   class Dog implements Animal{
     @Overwrite
     public String makeSound();{
        return "Wouff";
     }
   } 
   class Cat implements Animal{
     @Overwrite
     public String makeSound();{
        return "Meauw";
     }
   }
   ```

   it gets funny when we use this:

   ```
   List<Animal> animals = Arrays.asList(new Dog(), new Cat());
   for(Animal animal : animals)
       // each animal gives its own sound!
       System.out.println(animal.makeSound());
   ```

   output is:

   ```
     Wouff
     Meauw
   ```
2. Behavior Inheritance

   This is provided by *base classes* which could, but may not be abstract.
   The Point is that the method(s) which will be inherited by the *child class* are **not** *abstract*, this means they have a content.

   ```
   class BaseClass{
     public String commonBehavior(){
        return "common behavior of BaseClass called in "+getClass();
     } 
   }   

   class Child1 extends BaseClass {
     // may have own behavior, but not needed for the demo
   }

   class Child2 extends BaseClass {
     // same here
   }
   ```

   now we can call the common behavior on the child classes although they did not have any code of their own:

   ```
   System.out.println(new  Child1().commonBehavior()); 
   System.out.println(new  Child2().commonBehavior());
   ```

   The output of this is:

   ```
    common behavior of BaseClass called in Child1 
    common behavior of BaseClass called in Child2
   ```

Try it out.